# Doctrine ORM ManyToMany query by Object using Criteria

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I have this relations:
Exercise - Muscle
Every Exercies can be related to multiple muscles and every muscle can be related to many muscles.

So they are defined as a ManyToMany relation.

Now i want to query all the muscles related to a particular exercies.

I tried something like this:

```
$muscle = $muscleRepository->find(9);
$c = new Criteria();
$c->where(Criteria::expr()->in('muscles', [$muscle]));
$res = $er->matching($c);
dd($res->toArray());
```

But this gives me a notice "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null".
The notices appears whenever I try to do something with the LazyLoadCollection that comes from the ->matching call.

I've tried var_dumping and echoing things but the result is the same, so dd is not to be blamed.

I also tried contains and memberOf operators but with no luck.

Now I got things working writing an ugly workaround for this which involves removing the criteria and applying a ->filter function on the LazyLoadCollection but I would really like to handle this using Criteria class which seems to be made for this specific purpose.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The second parameter for `in` is documented as an array, try wrapping it in `[]`

Comment: Sorry, I tried this too but with no luck. I'll fix my code in the question though.

Comment: First, are you sure that `$muscle` has something in it? Second, I'm familiar with Doctrine, just not Criteria, are you sure that it takes entities? Can you pass it `9` instead to see if that kicks it it?

Comment: tried 9 as well, nothing... and Yes, I'm sure that $muscle is ok.

Comment: Okay, so then I'm assuming that `$er->matching($c);` is returning null then, right? So `$res` is null before the `dd`

Comment: $er->matching($c) returns a LazyLoadCollection, which crashes whenever I try to do something with it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can you update your question with this information and then we can delete this comment thread? It might help some other people debug this further. Specifically, it sounds like when you call `->toArray()` on your `LazyLoadCollection`, that's when you are getting a notice. Also, it is possible that `dd` itself is causing the problem because it isn't handling the collection in the way it was supposed to. You might want to try the simpler debugging tools like `echo` just to test this.